# How can I fix a keypress loop which stops when pressing another key?

Tags: c#, input, directx, low-level, sendinput

I have programmed a loop which spams spacebar (low-level input) when I hold down spacebar. This does work, but it suddenly stops working when I press any other key while holding spacebar. How can I fix it? I am using InputManager API from [here](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/117657/%2FArticles%2F117657%2FInputManager-library-Track-user-input-and-simulate).

```
        private void GlobalHookKBKeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (spacePressed == true)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Space)
            {
                spacePressed = false;
                timer1.Stop();
            }
        }
    }

    private void GlobalHookKBKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (checkBox2.Checked == true)
        {
            if (canJump == true)
            {
                if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Space)
                {
                    spacePressed = true;
                    timer2.Start();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (spacePressed == true)
        {
            Keyboard.KeyPress(Keys.Space);
        }
    }
```

Comment: `but it suddenly stops working when I press any other key while holding spacebar.` can you describe it in more detail?

Comment: The program starts timer2 when spacebar was held down, but when spacebar is still held down and I press any other key, for example W, it just stops working. I have to hold spacebar again to start the timer, even though I never released it, aka the keyup event shouldn't be triggered.

Comment: i dont understant what you want to do, when you press space, you activate the event keydown so when you release the space key you activate the keyUp event. so between these 2 events the space key is down. why you do a keypress(key.space) its nosense?

Comment: some general advice instead of comparing boolean values to true or false in your conditionals for example: (spacePressed == true) you can also just use if (spacePressed) you save typing time and it is less likely to create unwanted behavior